# Single event call when multiple others are all called?

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I have a list of objects, each having an `Updated` event: `public event System.Action Updated;` Now I would like to get a single event, when all my objects have fired their `Updated` event at least once.

What would be the cleanest way to implement this?

Note: I'm working in Unity, and it doesn't have to be thread-safe.

Comment: And what is wrong with your current approach? Do you have some errors? Or event is fired before all objects updated?

Comment: Maybe just call a method at the end of each event that uses boolean flags set by the events as they fire? `if (!AllFlags) { /* do nothing yet */ } else { /*do stuff now*/ }`

Comment: My current approach? I don't have any. Each object fires its Updated event fine, but I need to know when all have been updated.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would suggest that if you have event(s) that rely on other events being fired then your using the [wrong pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns). This question is very vague though so it's hard to tell

Comment: Agree with @DangerZone - Seems like these objects should each have an Updated property that gets set by their Updated event handler.  The Updated event handler for each of those objects should then call a method that looks through your list of objects and if they are all tagged as "updated", it can perform the action you want.

Comment: @DangerZone This is indeed simple and quite nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: @TheOddler Had wrote a solution for your problem wanted to paste some code and now it's 'on hold'

Comment: My code was : http://rextester.com/WRL30320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by writing a method to create a `Task` that will be completed the next time the event fires:

```
public static Task WhenUpdated(this IUpdatable updatable)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Action handler = null;
    handler = () =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        updatable.Updated -= handler;
    };
    updatable.Updated += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Once you have that you can use `WhenAll`, passing in the `Task` for each of the objects you have:

```
var task = Task.WhenAll(list.Select(item => item.WhenUpdated()));
```

That task will then be completed when all of the events have fired.  You can fire an even as a continuation if you want, or just expose that task so that consumers can add their own continuation to do whatever action is appropriate.